# Why shouldn't two AC sources be connected in parallel?

Tags: ac, ups

In data centers, servers usually have redundant power supplies, which makes it possible to plug them to two different UPS units. This way, the server continues to function correctly if one of the PSU goes down, or if one of the UPS units is shut down for replacement.

Some servers don't have redundant power supplies. In order to be able to still connect them to two UPS units (in order to be able to replace one unit without shutting down the server first), special devices called *transfer switches* are used: they can receive input from multiple sources, and provide power for single-corded equipment. A transfer switch is usually expensive and contains lots of electronics inside. Basically, automated transfer switches provide power from one source, and when they sense that the source is down, they fallback to another source.

What makes it impossible to have just a cable which would plug into two sources on one side, and to one server on another side? In other words, something like that:

[image]

but the other way around, i.e. not a cable with one male and two female connectors, but a cable with two male and one female connectors?

In other words, why is it possible to wire two DC power sources in parallel, but one cannot (or shouldn't) wire two AC sources in parallel? Is it because the waves may not be synchronized and could then cancel out each other? Or something else?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feb6xx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: exactly. Simply draw two sines of the same frequency, but with different phases. "Calculate" the difference between them (visually), and see what would happen on the cable between them, should you connect them. This is bascially AC current for very very beginners – AC has a phase. You might want to read up on basic theory.

Comment: Theoretically only two pure DC sources with exactly the same voltage can be parallel connected. Do it with batteries and you get away with it due to the battery impedance but there is energy loss due to the one with higher voltage discharging into the lower voltage one until equilibrium is reached (if ever). No difference for AC sources except that the potential circulating current can be tens, hundreds or thousands of amps.

Comment: A good thing here is that you asked before ordering say 500 custom cords that you quite well described. A more decisive director would have ordered them without asking. Some time after the cords were delivered an unlucky subordinate of that director would have been fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When two DC sources are paralleled, blocking diodes prevent back feeding from one supply to the other. The supply with the highest voltage will always supply current without being affected by the other.

There is no comparably simple and effective provision for paralleling two AC supplies. Two AC supplies from the utility can be obtained with matching phases and voltages, but if one goes down, it must be disconnected to prevent back feeding. Even dealing with small voltage or phase differences is not particularly easy.

Answer (score 5):

*Note: I am not trained in electrical safety. Do not rely on this post for safety advice. I know you are asking theoretically, but I feel like I should put this disclaimer here anyway.*

> Is it because the waves may not be synchronized and could then cancel out each other? Or something else?

That is the main reason, but the consequences are worse than just having the voltage cancel out.

Let's imagine the worst case where the sources are perfectly unsynchronized (180 degrees apart - opposite voltages all the time) and that the voltage is at the maximum when you make the connection. Remember that AC is just time-varying DC - at the instant when you connect them together, you have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN8pWs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You've connected two voltage sources in a loop. Forget the load - what happens to the voltage sources? Well, V1 tries really really hard to make the voltage 240V, and V2 tries really really hard to make the voltage *negative* 240V. V1 makes lots of current flow from the bottom to the top, and V2 makes lots of current flow from the top to the bottom again. This is basically a short circuit, but short circuiting two sources at the same time.

If V1 and V2 are alkaline batteries, they might [get quite warm](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30594/short-circuit-an-alkaline-battery). If they're NiCad batteries, they might [get hot enough to melt plastic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fj5BLo27yw). If they're lithium rechargeable batteries, they will definitely [burn up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsUppV-0QTU).

If V1 and V2 are inverters (as in double-conversion UPSes) the output circuit will probably blow up (literally).

If V1 and V2 are different phases of mains power, you'll get a big spark and pop the circuit breaker. If enough power is available, [the spark (known as an arc flash) can be big enough to cause serious injuries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY). The main power feed to the datacenter probably *can* do that. I don't *think* you're likely to be seriously injured by plugging an IEC connector into a short circuit (even on two different voltage sources), but I still wouldn't try it.

If V1 and V2 are standby UPSes, running on the same phase of mains power, they should both be in phase - until one of them switches to battery power, at which time it will blow up because its inverter is now in parallel with the mains power.

Answer (score 3):

#### Danger to Wires

With this type of setup, while your *intention* may be that it would only ever be used with "one cable's worth of electricity", there is no guarantee. So someone could use the exact same configuration to get **double power** - e.g., 20A from circuit 1 and 20A from circuit 2 in order to have 40A total. There are a bunch of problems with this. In particular:

- Each of these two cables will have hot & neutral. *In theory, the current on the neutrals and hots will be balanced - 1/2 the current on one wire in each pair.* Actually there is no guarantee of that, but **even if there is under normal circumstances**, if **one** of the neutrals breaks due to a wiring problem somewhere, all of the hot - e.g., 40A in this example, will return on the other neutral. But neutral wires are not normally protected from overload in the US, so this would result in the wire handling twice its nominal capacity and potentially start a fire.

#### Danger to People

Normally, one circuit break is flipped to turn off power to a device. Let's say you have one of these 2 circuits also used for LED lights above the servers - just a few watts, so no big deal. Someone comes in to work on the light fixture. The servers are not on at the time. He starts work by turning off the breaker and verifying it is off and now has exposed wires from the fixture. You come in and turn on the server.

- The server can **backfeed** power from circuit 1 into circuit 2, which will now make the rest of circuit 2 - including the exposed wires on the light fixture **hot** and potentially fatal.

Comment: I think it's even simpler than that - connecting two different phases of a 3-phase supply or two different inverters is likely to make something melt or explode.

Comment: @user253751 You are correct about the problem that would cause. I am more concerned about the "no problem initially, so I'll use it...and think nothing will ever go wrong" situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is incorrect for experts and only applies to newbs.

When you apply voltage sources in parallel, the impedance, voltage and phase must be known before connection to know the resulting  power being transferred , if it will be stable, safe and performs expected task.  This is why an experienced Tech. or Eng. should be consulted.

This is done all the time with the AC grid, DC battery boost start etc.

e.g.

- if ESR total is 10mOhms and voltage difference is 1V then connecting both batteries together results in a current of  100 Amps which may or may not cause damage.

### Answer to your photo in question. (wrong example)

This is just a Y splitter cable to go from 1 source  to 2 loads with female receptacles being the source of power.

If you did the opposite from two outlets, with the exact same voltage, **there is no advantage** except current sharing or doubling up wire capacity but you still might exceed the breaker rating before each outlet rating.

Comment: This is more technically correct but does not detract from safety issues in other answers.  parallel systems must have design to control sharing or power transfer to enhance redundancy.

Answer (score -3):

Adding ac voltages requires complex algebra.Use the complex v representation for real and imaginary voltages.

Comment: We're only dealing with real voltages here. The simple worst case conditions (supplies in anti-phase) give an adequate result to show why this is a very bad idea. No complex algebra required. Remember that you can [edit] your answer at any time to improve it. Welcome to EE.SE.